# Iterating over an array reference

Tags: perl

```perl
# data $bug
{ 
 'keyword_objects' => [ 
    bless( { 'id' => 15, 'name' => 'CRASH'}, 'SomeModule::SomeFilename' ), 
    bless( { 'id' => 6, 'name' => 'CUSTOMER' }, 'SomeModule::SomeFilename' ) ],
 'category' => 'error'
}
```

```perl
   foreach my $keyword ($bug->{keyword_objects}) {
     print Dumper($keyword);
   }
```

It prints the whole of `keyword_objects` instead of the individual items in it. Now it should be obvious to you that I know so little about Perl, I'd like to also ask what is the right way to reference `name` in each keyword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To iterate over the elements in your array ref, you need to *dereference* it. `foreach` needs a list.

```perl
foreach my $keyword ( @{ $bug->{keyword_objects} } ) {
```

Your objects are hash references, so you could reach into their internals like this:

```perl
$keyword->{name}
```

However, messing with internals is not a good idea. Instead, you should write accessors and call them as a method.

```perl
$keyword->name
```